# Sum of switch-triggered integers in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I've implemented a VHDL program that sums up the positions of switches and shows it on a 7-segment LED, but I've had to use lots of temporaries and a division. Is there a better way?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity light is
  port(
        LEDR : out std_logic_vector(0 to 9);
        LEDG : out std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
        SW : in std_logic_vector(0 to 9);
        KEY : in std_logic_vector(0 to 3);
        HEX0 : out std_logic_vector(0 to 6);
        HEX1 : out std_logic_vector(0 to 6);
        HEX2 : out std_logic_vector(0 to 6);
        HEX3 : out std_logic_vector(0 to 6)
  );
end light;



architecture arch of light is

signal sum, sum2 : integer := 0;
signal x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9 : integer := 0;

function led_value(x:integer)
    return std_logic_vector is
begin
    case x is
       when 0 => return "0000001";
        when 1 => return "1001111";
        when 2 => return "0010010";
        when 3 => return "0000110";
        when 4 => return "1001100";
        when 5 => return "0100100";
        when 6 => return "0100000";
        when 7 => return "0001111";
        when 8 => return "0000000";
        when 9 => return "0000100";
        when others => return "1111111";
    end case;
end led_value;

begin
    x1 <= 1 when sw(1) = '1' else 0;
    x2 <= 2 when sw(2) = '1' else 0;
    x3 <= 3 when sw(3) = '1' else 0;
    x4 <= 4 when sw(4) = '1' else 0;
    x5 <= 5 when sw(5) = '1' else 0;
    x6 <= 6 when sw(6) = '1' else 0;
    x7 <= 7 when sw(7) = '1' else 0;
    x8 <= 8 when sw(8) = '1' else 0;
    x9 <= 9 when sw(9) = '1' else 0;

    sum <= x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9;
    sum2 <= (sum - sum mod 10) / 10;

    hex0 <= led_value(sum mod 10);
    hex1 <= led_value(sum2);
    hex2 <= led_value(11);
    hex3 <= led_value(11);
end arch;
```

Comment: Do you have a preference in which base the switches should be counted?

Comment: @Mast well the idea was to count them in Base 10, so SW(1) contributes a 1 if switched, SW(8) an 8, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some old question, but lets answer it.

Synthesis software is not that dumb. It will evaluate the potential outcomes of a function and generate reduced logic from that. Often you have to aid the synthesis software somewhat. You could do that by writing a function which internally resolves the things you want.

N.B. constraining the range of your integers keep the resource usage low. Else everything will be implemented as a 32-bit value

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity light is
  port(
        SW : in std_logic_vector(0 to 9); -- why 'to' and not 'downto'??
        KEY : in std_logic_vector(0 to 3); -- downto is normally used
        HEX0 : out std_logic_vector(0 to 6);
        HEX1 : out std_logic_vector(0 to 6);
        HEX2 : out std_logic_vector(0 to 6);
        HEX3 : out std_logic_vector(0 to 6);
        LEDR : out std_logic_vector(0 to 9);
        LEDG : out std_logic_vector(0 to 7)
  );
end light;

architecture arch of light is
    function hex_decode(x:integer)
        return std_logic_vector is
    begin
        case x is
            when 0 => return "0000001";
            when 1 => return "1001111";
            when 2 => return "0010010";
            when 3 => return "0000110";
            when 4 => return "1001100";
            when 5 => return "0100100";
            when 6 => return "0100000";
            when 7 => return "0001111";
            when 8 => return "0000000";
            when 9 => return "0000100";
            when others => return "1111111";
        end case;
    end hex_decode;

    function add_input(input : std_logic_vector(0 to 9))
        return natural is
        variable sum : natural range 0 to 45 := 0;
    begin
        for i in 1 to 9 loop
            if input(i)='1' then
                sum := sum + i;
            end if;
        end loop;
        return sum;
    end function add_input;

    function select_decimal(input : natural; sel: natural)
        return natural is
        variable output : natural range 0 to 9;
    begin
        output := (input / (10**sel)) mod 10;
        return output;
    end function select_decimal;

    signal switch_value : natural range 0 to 45;
begin

    switch_value <= add_input(sw);

    hex0 <= hex_decode(select_decimal(switch_value, 0));
    hex1 <= hex_decode(select_decimal(switch_value, 1));
    hex2 <= hex_decode(select_decimal(switch_value, 2));
    hex3 <= hex_decode(select_decimal(switch_value, 3));
end arch;
```

Result in Vivado:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start RTL Component Statistics 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Detailed RTL Component Info : 
+---Adders : 
       8 Input      6 Bit       Adders := 1     
+---Muxes : 
      11 Input      7 Bit        Muxes := 2     
       2 Input      6 Bit        Muxes := 1     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished RTL Component Statistics 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Report Cell Usage: 
+------+-------+------+
|      |Cell   |Count |
+------+-------+------+
|1     |CARRY4 |     2|
|2     |LUT2   |     2|
|3     |LUT3   |     1|
|4     |LUT4   |     4|
|5     |LUT5   |     7|
|6     |LUT6   |    15|
|7     |IBUF   |     9|
|8     |OBUF   |    28|
|9     |OBUFT  |    18|
+------+-------+------+

Report Instance Areas: 
+------+---------+-------+------+
|      |Instance |Module |Cells |
+------+---------+-------+------+
|1     |top      |       |    86|
+------+---------+-------+------+
```

Comment: You should avoid the division by using the [double dabble algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) to convert binary to decimal numbers. The binary to 7-segment encoder is low-active. That not a good design choice. Low-active conversation should be performed at the top-level VHDL file.

Comment: -1. Your function doesn't include bit 0 of the input switches. The range of the integer makes no sense. A) so sum will never exceed 10, B) synthesis will strip off​ unused bits anyhow regardless of 32 or 6 bit. Moreover, 0..45 is not a power of two range. Initialization of variables does not work in Quartus. Note the original design uses only 2 digits.

Comment: @paebbels you can either complain, or write your own, better answer. This question was asked six months ago, so you've had enough time to answer it. But nobody did, so I figured, I'd give it a try.

Comment: But @paebbels, I don't understand your second complaint about the range of `sum`. sum+0 is still sum, isn't it? And 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=45? Did you misread the question? I myself never had an issue with variable initialization, even in Quartus.

Comment: And I tried with no constraint on the integer, but vivado synthesis did _not_ drop unused bits. I would show you if you tell me how to contract you.

Comment: Oh sorry, I now see my two false interpretations. x1...x9 have an increasing value. This explains why `sw(0)` in unused. I know that Vivado is not the best :)

Comment: To my knowledge, the Quartus variable initialization bug was not fixed in the last revisions. My last test on that bug was Altera Quartus II 14.0. Have you tested this issue with Intel Quartus Prime 16.0? You'll find my user name as one of the maintainers of PoC.

Comment: @Paebbels I get my new computer today, and need to install it, so I cannot test it. I've been seachin for more information on what you call the "Quartus variable initialization bug", but cannot find it. Can you give me a link. If this really is a bug, then it is a very serious one. I know massive amounts of code that depend on variable initialization like this.

Comment: There is no link for this bug. We discovered it while developing PoC. Now we have a design rule to not use default expressions in functions hosted in packages. Maybe on could search our Git when we changed the code. I think it could be found by blaming [this line](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/utils.vhdl?ts=2#L368) or [that line](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/strings.vhdl?ts=2#L871). I also know from another designer (not in our team) who says don't trust that variables are initialized to 'left. I also know another tool that caused constraint e

Comment: How can there be no link for this bug? I mean: more people should have encountered it. It should at least has to be discussed on the Altera/Intel forums? Are they (Intel) aware of this bug?

Comment: At the time as I discovered that bug, we didn't have the infrastructure to easily create minimal examples and to automatically extract bug reports from the framework. Since then I had other bugs with higher priority on my list to report to the vendors. This list has currently over 5 pending bugs for various vendors. It's really hard to report bugs to some vendors if you have no payed or just a university license ... and even if, they decny the bug or alter their documentation instead of fixing the issue (Xilinx)! We should talk outside of StackExchange about that topic.